# Execute a query on a particular MySQL thread - IDEA

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an idea, but I'm not sure whether it is possible or not. / It is already available or not. Just sharing my points here, to get the suggestion whether it is possible in MySQL

**Issues:**

Say a small change is done in a query in a feature of a product and got released in production, due to this change it takes more time to complete the execution of the query.
Suddenly there is a surge from customers for this feature. Then the DB loaded heavily due to multiple queries of this feature, because of this feature query other features in the product also got affected (other simple queries) as the DB is loaded.

**Why this occurred:**

Say my **innodb_thread_concurrency** is 20. For ex: If 100 such costly query comes in, MySQL will use all THREADS available and process the query by doing context switching. Due to this other simple queries gets affected.

**What can be one of the possible solution:**

May be move the costly queries to slave, but still the same will occur in slave and slave get loaded.

**What I think could be a better solution:**

Say my
innodb_thread_concurrency = 20.
CPU CORE = 36

Here I have allocated 20 Threads from CPU to MYSQL. In this 20 Thread, I will make a split up in Application level, which query will be executed in which thread.

**Split 20 thread into 3 Set based on priority:**

Thread Priority vs Thread Count - which should be configurable.
Ex:
Low Priority: 4
Medium Priority: 6
High Priority: 10

**High Priority:**

1. Say very simple queries. Like querying a config tables
2. Insert, Update, Delete queries
3. Basically these queries are the basic one for the products to run
4. Mostly gets executed under 100ms to 1 sec

**Medium Priority:**

1. Queries which are less important than core queries, which might take little extra time mostly 1 - 5 seconds

**Low Priority:**

1. Log Table queries, Analytics queries
2. Time taking queries greater than 5 sec

**The rule here is:**

-> The configured query should be executed only in that particular **Priority_Threads** and context switching also should be done only among those **Priority_Threads**.

-> All the queries should be configure in product level which query executes in which **THREAD**, if this query is simple and important, it will be executed using **High_Priority_Thread**, as our assumption is this query will be executed in 100ms.

Let come to our case which loaded the DB and affected all the queries, with this support we would have executed our query in **Low_Priority_Thread**. As said above, If 100 this type of queries come to **Low_Priority_Thread**, only that Priority Thread get affected as context switching will occur only between **Low_Priority_Thread**. So other **Priority_Threads** will be free which will serve their own queries which is assigned.

This can be used in different use cases:

1. If a new feature comes in Beta version, we can execute this queries in **Low_Priority_Thread**. If any issue in this feature query, it won't affect the core queries in other threads.
2. Any changes done to the existing query in **High_Priority** query, we can change its **Priority_Thread** type to lower level for the time being until it is stable.

Please share your views on this. Is something like this possible in MYSQL, or any other databases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL Resource Groups

> MySQL supports creation and management of resource groups, and permits
> assigning threads running within the server to particular groups so
> that threads execute according to the resources available to the
> group. Group attributes enable control over its resources, to enable
> or restrict resource consumption by threads in the group. DBAs can
> modify these attributes as appropriate for different workloads.

[MySQL :: MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual :: 5.1.16 Resource Groups](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resource-groups.html)

---

**Few other reference links:**

https://medium.com/synaptic-tech/scaling-our-platform-using-mysql-8-resource-groups-e7c09d2cedd7

https://dzone.com/articles/mysql-8-load-fine-tuning-with-resource-groups

Answer (score 1):

**A case against thread priorities**

I suspect that if "thread priorities" were useful, they would already have been implemented.

Here is one problem that argues against such:

1. A low-priority thread gets some time.
2. That low thread has locked a row because he is about to Update it.  (Say, a "Likes" counter.)
3. A high-priority thread comes along and needs that row, but is now blocked.  (Oops, he is now as slow as the low thread.)
4. Another high-priority thread comes along...  Well, I'll let you finish the murder mystery story.

The best thing to do (in most cases) is to work on speeding up the slowest queries.  Priority is less important than how fast it can get out of the way.

Keep in mind that "context switching" is necessary to handle inter-thread coordination.  And probably the number of switches is the same, with or without priorities.

"100ms to 1 sec" -- Even these are worth optimizing.

A problem I sometimes see stems from allowing too many concurrent processes.  I like the grocery store analogy...

**Crowded grocery store analogy**

Put simply, if "too many" people are in the store at the same time, no one will get out very fast; everyone is slowed down.

Now let's say some people are more privileged and the others must step aside to allow them to go faster.  Well, suppose I (low-priority) may be standing in front of the deli counter and the single clerk is slicing some meat for me.  You (high-priority) come along and demand that the clerk stop with my order to handle your request.  This will lead to the clerk being less efficient (because of the half-finished order sitting in the meat slicer).  And more customers will be standing behind you.

**Freeway traffic**

Studies have determined that metering lights on freeway ramps make freeways *more* efficient.  Yeah, it is counter-intuitive.  Also, frequent lane switching on the freeway actually requires *more* space.  Etc.

**Alternative proposal**

So, Use the slowlog to determine which query types are the most burdensome on the system, then provide a sample, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT`.  We can probably speed it up.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your points noted it.  We thought of solving this DB loaded issue for few cases where queries can't be optimised for the time being. Until it is fixed thought using this flow for few edge cases. 
Also, I came to know that it is supported in MySQL 8 - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resource-groups.html

Comment: @vinieth - I would be interested to hear how well Resource Groups work for you.

Comment: Case 1: we have a feature where a particular feature query(can't be optimised) always takes time, if 20 such queries comes in will load all the available threads in MySQL. Other simple queries which comes-in take some extra time than the usual execution time, here we will create resource group with around 3 threads, only for this feature.  So other simple queries can run without issue, but this issue causing feature execution time will increase due to limited resource but which is not an issue in our case let it take time.

Comment: Case 2: If any query causing issue in production, due to some issue we can't optimise the query in hotfix(as it may require restructuring table design) . So We will create a resource-group on-demand and using a configuration in app level where we will mention all the queries of this request  need to use this resource group, after enabling it the code will dynamically add resource group optimiser hint for this request uri  queries alone.  So other features won't get affected